# Running Gradle tasks which don't exit in parallel

Tags: gradle

I am currently running a number of tasks which don't exit to execute all my mocks.  I'm using this script:

```
../gradlew :pm:pm-mock-1:run \
           :pm:pm-mock-2:run \
           :pm:pm-mock-3:run \
           :pm:pm-mock-4:run \
           :pm:pm-mock-5:run \
           :pm:pm-mock-6:run \
           :pm:pm-mock-7:run \
           :pm:pm-mock-8:run \
           :pm:pm-mock-9:run \
           --parallel \
           --max-workers=10
```

Ideally I would like a single task to run all of the mocks, but if I have

```
task runMocks(dependsOn: [
    'pm-mock-1:run',
    'pm-mock-2:run',
    'pm-mock-3:run',
    'pm-mock-4:run',
    'pm-mock-5:run',
    'pm-mock-6:run',
    'pm-mock-7:run',
    'pm-mock-8:run',
    'pm-mock-9:run'])
```

then it waits for the first task to end, rather than running them in parallel.

How would I replicate my script so that I can run

```
../gradle :runMocks
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you gradle.properties file add

```
org.gradle.parallel=true 
org.gradle.workers.max=10
```

You can read more about gradle.properties file at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html

Comment: Thanks.  I have tried this, but it only seems to be running 5 tasks.  I was hoping for some kind of  "run just these in parallel" command, but will have to work around it.

Comment: What is you bump the max workers to a higher number? It may be that the pool is being used for other tasks too.

Comment: Doesn't make a difference.  I tried changing to 20 workers